# foreach in Razor Syntax in SubscribeEventMapping

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

This is the error. 
I'm trying to get data from DB using MVC Controller returning to View.

**Error CS1579  foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'SubscriberEventMapping' because 'SubscriberEventMapping' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'**

```
@model WebApplicationLPISubscriber.Models.SubscriberEventMapping
@using WebApplicationLPISubscriber.Models;

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()



        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SubscriberID)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SubscriberID)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EventTypeName)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Year)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CalendarStartDate)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CalendarEndDate)
                </th>



            </tr>
            </table>

            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SubscriberID)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EventTypeName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Year)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CalendarStartDate)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CalendarEndDate)
                    </td>
                </tr> 
             }
```

Comment: can you share the **Action** in the *controller*?

Answer (score 0):

The error happens in foreach. Your model declaration `@model WebApplicationLPISubscriber.Models.SubscriberEventMapping` **IS NOT a List or Collection type.** Foreach can't loop through your model because it is not a list.

In order for foreach to work, use `List<ModelName>`. See the code below.

```
@using WebApplicationLPISubscriber.Models;
@model List<WebApplicationLPISubscriber.Models.SubscriberEventMapping>
```